# can i disable hotlink protection for links clicked within domain

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking

have added hotlink protection to my .htaccess file. It works fine and stops images and pdf's loading if they are called from another domain. However, I don't want files to be blocked if people follow a link to them from within my domain. For example, if there is a link to [www.mydomain.com/file.pdf](http://www.mydomain.com/file.pdf) on the page [www.mydomain.com/somefile.htm](http://www.mydomain.com/somefile.htm), at the moment that pdf will be blocked from loading. Is it possible to stop this happening?

Thanks

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.example.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.example.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|JPG|pdf)$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: what hotlink protection? post the code

Comment: Seems like your current "hotlink protection" (which is not visible to us) does _not_really work at all, but merely blocks every request, right?

Comment: It does work, yes. Maybe I just missed a line out of the code in the file when I copied it here which is why it looks like it doesn't work. Great constructive comments though. Really, I just wanted to know if it is possible to do what I want, and if so whether somebody could be kind enough to share that knowledge with me. Forget my current. If you were starting from scratch to achieve what I want to, please can you tell me if that is possible and if so how you would do it. Thank you.